# BigInteger string representation with decimal places

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, biginteger

I'm trying to create a decimal representation of a big integer when it's divided by something. The follwoing is the code which does it, basically I want the precision to be of 2 places.

```
    public string GetDecimal(BigInteger bigInteger,int divisor)
    {
        var remainder   = BigInteger.Remainder(bigInteger, divisor);
        var dividend    = BigInteger.Divide(bigInteger, divisor);

        var d = ((double)remainder / divisor);
        var decimalPart = Math.Round(d, 2);
        var retValue = dividend + decimalPart.ToString(".00");
        return retValue;
    }
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this please?

Thanks,
-Mike

Comment: You can do the first two lines with one DivRem call -- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.divrem.aspx

Comment: The variable `dividend` should be named `quotient`.  "Dividend" means "the thing that is divided"; the dividend is analogous to the numerator of a fraction.  In other words, `quotient = dividend / divisor`.

Comment: Your code is actually broken. Test it with `999`/`1000`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably not convert the types and do the long division on your own.  This should work with any BigInteger value.

I'm sure there's room for improvement here...

```
public string GetDecimal(BigInteger bigInteger, int divisor)
{
    BigInteger remainder;
    var quotient = BigInteger.DivRem(bigInteger, divisor, out remainder);

    const int decimalPlaces = 2;
    var decimalPart = BigInteger.Zero;
    for(int i = 0; i < decimalPlaces; i++)
    {
        var div = (remainder*10)/divisor;

        decimalPart *= 10;
        decimalPart += div;

        remainder = remainder*10 - div*divisor;
    }

    var retValue = quotient.ToString() + "." + decimalPart.ToString(new string('0', decimalPlaces));
    return retValue;
}
```

Comment: Does this output a precision of 2 zeros? I only get a precision of a zero like:7.0 and not 7.00.

Comment: @Mike: I did not test trailing zeros.  I will check.  --Edited to address all zeros

Answer (score 0):

The built in .net `decimal` type is 128bit, and works with similar rounding constructs of other types.  Is this number not large enough?

Comment: No, it's not. Hence going for BigInteger.

Comment: Okay, I assume you're using this for monetary calculations (as you're rounding to 2 decimal places), I'd suggest you use `decimal` instead of `double` to prevent precision problems.

Comment: @Matthew if he's rounding to two decimal places anyway, he's not going to be affected by precision issues of `double`, which don't show up until you get well past the 10th decimal place.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing maths on it especially using less accurate types like double.
simply build a string with all but the last two digits, append a decimal point and then put the last one in.

e.g. Something like

```
int precision = 2;
negative = 0;
if (bigInteger < 0)
{
   negative = 1;
}
String strValue = bigInteger.ToString().PadRight(precision + negative + 1,'0');
return strValue.Insert(strValue.Length - precision, ".");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var s=((bigInteger*200+divisor)/(2*(BigInteger)divisor)).ToString();
return s.Insert(".",s.Length-2);
```

This code only works for positive values, and uses `AwayFromZero` midpoint rounding. I also didn't care about localization issues.